# How to split Apache Druid hstorical and middlemanager nodes

Tags: time-series, druid

In a clustered deployment of druid, the document doesn't mention how to split `historical` and `middlemanager` nodes into two (or more) separate nodes. It only mentions the port ranges they can accept. For running data-servers, druid says we must execute this script:

`./bin/start-cluster-data-server`

In we run this script in two different machines, how one of them act as `middlemanager` and the other as `historical` node?

Answer (score 1):

If you `cat` the quickstart scripts, you'll see that each one calls a Perl script called `supervise`.  Here is what you'll see inside `start-cluster-data-server`, for example:

```
exec "$WHEREAMI/supervise" -c "$WHEREAMI/../conf/supervise/cluster/data.conf"
```

The configuration file following `-c` contains information about the processes to start.  For example, here's the `data.conf` file:

```
:verify bin/verify-java

historical bin/run-druid historical conf/druid/cluster/data
middleManager bin/run-druid middleManager conf/druid/cluster/data
```

You can see then how you can configure your own start scripts and a `.conf` file to go with it that will spawn only those processes that you want to run on a particular node.